# N'hésitez pas à l'essayer ou N'hésitez pas de l'essayer ?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot

J'aimerais savoir si ces deux expressions existent ou bien si une seulement est correcte, ainsi que leurs cas d'utilisation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seule la première (*N'hésitez pas **à** l'essayer*) est correcte.

Answer (score 4):

*Hésiter de* (tout comme *hésiter pour*, encore plus rare) [est vieilli](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/h%C3%A9siter) au point que [même l'Académie française le dit](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/h%C3%A9siter).